# How can I insert a sorted linked list into another sorted one while maintaining it sorted?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

How can I insert a sorted linked list(L2) as a whole list into another sorted linked list(L1) and maintain the both sorted?

the method head should be : `void insertList(LinkedList L2)`

for example :

```
L1 = 1 → 2 → 3 → 10
L2 = 4 → 5 → 6
```

after calling the method the L1 list should be:

```
1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6 → 10
```

How can it be done?

Comment: `list1.addAll(index, list2)` if you are using the `java.util.LinkedList` class.

Comment: @khelwood No. Did you even read the question and the provided example? It's pretty clear from the example the OP wants get two sorted lists and get a sorted list as a result.

Comment: @amit From the OP's use of the words "insert a linked list into another linked list" I assumed he/she was trying to insert a linked list into another linked list. Of course, that was before you edited the word "sorted" into the question, changing its meaning.

Comment: Short answer: Recursive. One by one. And this is stackoverflow.com, not domyhomeowrk.org ! Please read about this sites guidelines, questions like this one are likely to attract downvotes and bad karma!

Comment: @khelwood There is a pretty clear example + sorting tag, I find it pretty clear what he wants to do..

Comment: I want to vote for your answer but I can't I don't why , but really thank you for this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the merge phase of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

it can be done in LinkedList simply by iterating the two together, and pushing to a result list the smallest element every time.

Pseudo code:

```
iter1 = list1.iterator()
iter2 = list2.iterator()
//before these commands make sure the lists are not empty:
curr1 = iter1.next(); 
curr2 = iter2.next();
List result = new LinkedList();
while curr1 != null && curr2 != null {
   if curr1 < curr2 { 
          result.add(curr1);
          curr1 = list1.next();
   } else { 
          result.add(curr2);
          curr2 = list2.next();
   }
}
while (curr1 != null) {
   result.add(curr1);
   curr1 = curr1.next();
}
while (curr2 != null) {
   result.add(curr2);
   curr2 = curr1.next();
}
```

Small note: in the case of linked-list, you can optimize it to run in-place and modify one of the lists instead of creating a new list, if needed, using the [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) interface and the `add()` method. The algorithm is pretty similar, just need to be extra careful when inserting elements about invoking extra `next()`.

I leave it to you to modify the algorithm to modify `list` in place, because it should be pretty clear how to do it once the above algorithm is understood.

Comment: The algorithm works for ArrayList as well.

Comment: @StephenC For ArrayList though you cannot do it in-place in O(n) (as I described at the end of the answer).